# What is wrong with the mapflat

Tags: java

I got the compilation error: The method `mapflat((<no type> s) -> Arrays.stream(s.split(".")))` is undefined for the type Stream for the following code.

What is the problem?

```
Arrays.stream(new String[] {"a.b.c", "d.e.f"}).mapflat(s->Arrays.stream(s.split("."))).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Off-topic: _Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused a simple typographical error._

Comment: Read the error message again, as it's a rather common compiler error: "The method .. is undefined for the type .."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `mapflat` method.

You want [`flatMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-)

```
<R> Stream<R> flatMap(Function<? super T, ? extends Stream<? extends R>> mapper);
```

The function takes a type `T` (the `Stream` type) and returns a `Stream<R>`, the method returns a `Stream<R>`:

```
Arrays.stream(new String[] {"a.b.c", "d.e.f"}).
        flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split("."))).
        forEach(System.out::println);
```

Also worth noting that [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) uses regex so `split(".")` won't work. You need to use `split("\\.")`

Answer (score 2):

`Stream` does not declare or inherit a method named `mapflat` that accepts a single argument.